# Codeigniter 2.1.4 and php 5.3.27 Error

Tags: php, codeigniter

Getting the following error with CI 2.1.4 and PHP 5.3.27

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Only variable references should be returned by reference

Filename: core/Common.php

Line Number: 257
```

I've seen this reported before but the [accepted resolution](https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/244510/) isn't working for me. I just get a blank white page.

The accepted resolution is to change line 257 from:

```
return $_config[0] =& $config;
```

to

```
$_config[0] =& $config;
return $_config[0];
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: If white page then search for error in error log and paste it in question.